# Could not dropna from a dataframe after filling some column missing values with a pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pipeline

My data has 75130 rows × 36 columns, I plan to fill some column's 'NA' with mode filling and some with median. I just learned about the imputer and starts to practice it on my dataset.

```
An example of my dataFrame:
           y1   y2    y3    y4
    0      2    Nan   1     0.3
    1      Nan  Nan   2     0.4
    2      2    Nan   3     1.0
    3      3    Nan   4     2.0
    4      4    Nan   Nan   Nan
    5      5    Nan   Nan   Nan
```

After running a pipeline that carried out mode filling on y1 and median filling on y3, I want to dropna on y2 and y4  but the result I am getting is an empty dataframe with no values in rows and column

Please what can i do apart from running a long line of code to fillna.

Comment: Its pretty hard for us to comment without seeing any data. Please share a sample dataframe with expected output.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Your last question just blew up in my face what was going on. I need to get rid of the column with all Nan which is y2 first.

Comment: Look at what you've put in the comment and what you've put in the question itself. Explanations don't match. `I need to get rid of the column with all Nan` should have been in the question. Anyway, I've put the answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.dropna` with `how=all`:

This will drop only columns which has `Nan` in all rows.

```
In [111]: df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') 
Out[111]: 
    y1   y3   y4
0    2    1  0.3
1  NaN    2  0.4
2    2    3  1.0
3    3    4  2.0
4    4  NaN  NaN
5    5  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: @AbimbolaOjikutu Please let me know if the answer worked.